# No java project option in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, wizard

There may well be a very simple answer to this but having googled for an hour, I am resorting to asking here.

I am simply trying to install eclipse Indigo(3.7.2) on Ubuntu 12.04 and get it to let me make a java application.

I have used:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

to get eclipse, which also installs the jdt package needed for making java projects.

However, when I navigate to new -> project, I am not given the option of a java project wizard (see screenshot).

[image: New eclipse project]

Anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT: Dowloading the .tar.gz myself and unpacking it seems to have worked fine. I'm not sure why apt-get didn't work.

Comment: I suspect you downloaded the wrong instance of eclipse. They have a bunch of flavors, not all are for java. What version did you download?

Comment: Like I say I just used apt-get, so I presume it picked the right version? I have 32-bit ubuntu 12.04 on my machine and the eclipse version is: 3.7.2

Comment: Can you check the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep eclipse` to make sure the `eclipse-jdt` is correctly installed?

Answer (score 35):

Window > Open Perspective > Java

I feel like an idiot for how long it took me to figure this out.  It's not very intuitive now, is it?  >.<

Comment: there is no such menu option

Answer (score 12):

I was with the same problem. Try doing that:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get remove eclipse
sudo apt-get purge eclipse
rm -r ~/.eclipse
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

I didn't need to remove all the locations which showed up on *whereis eclipse*, like Steve Beer said.

Besides, you can also try doing

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall eclipse-jdt
```

if the previous commands don't work out.

Comment: I had same problem for me yum install eclipse-jdt worked

Comment: I had the same problem, your first solution worked for me. Thanks a lot, man!

Comment: +1 except that you should probably manually download and run `tar` because when I ran `sudo apt-get install eclipse` it installed Kepler instead of Luna.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it in deleting the entire ~/.eclipse directory along with everything in the workspace of eclipse. When I started eclipse after this, it was again possible to add java projects.

Comment: Remember that there are also hidden files in the workspace of eclipse. Those should be deleted also.

Comment: Be aware that the problem may reappear if you upgrade eclipse using the 'check for updates' menu item.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found out it was because I had installed another version of eclipse which I had downloaded manually. I simply removed the package again ("sudo apt-get remove eclipse") and deleted everything concerning eclipse:

- ~/.eclipse
- ~/workspace
- everything that showed up on "whereis eclipse"

and then reinstalled it using "sudo apt-get install eclipse". Worked fine for me.

Comment: Manual tinkering like this will probably cause your system to lose important information, and that might result in your losing the ability to manage the package via apt-get. I would recommend other methods before doing this, and if you finally decide to do it, proceed with caution.

Comment: Removing eclipse from /usr/lib/eclipse is a BIG mistake. A lot of hastle would follow.... going through fixing this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the JDK is installed. `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

also make sure that the installer is up to date : `sudo apt-get update` , `sudo apt-get upgrade`

You have another option. Try downloading eclipse from the Eclipse website www.eclipse.org

download the appropriate version for your machine and try running it from the command line directly yourDownloadPath/eclipse

- Don't forget to add the executable permission(chmod +x) if necessary

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Same as @thiagowfx answered, just need to add * in last commant

```
sudo apt-get remove eclipse*
sudo apt-get purge eclipse*
rm -r ~/.eclipse*
rm -r workspace*
```

Then install the eclipse

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

Answer (score -1):

these both commands completely solved the problem for me:

sudo apt-get install --reinstall eclipse-jdt

sudo apt-get update

Comment: This is similar to @thiagowfx's post