# Eclipse does not show Java EE perspective only when it's run with super user privilege

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-wtp

I have Eclipse CDT Luna service release 2 installed on Ubuntu 15.10. I have installed WTP, developed a dynamic web project and tested it with tomcat 8.

There are other projects related to this project that need to be run as root. When I open eclipse using sudo, I can't see Java EE perspective (I have enabled GUI root login as well and the problem exists there too).

After googling enough number of hours, I went ahead and installed WTP on eclipse again as root. But, I can't see Java EE perspective when I select Window->Open Perspective->Other..!
I restarted eclipse not with the root privilege and it popped up a window telling I need to update those plugins again. When I clicked No and checked for Java EE perspective it was missing. I restarted eclipse again, updated after the same pop up.

Now, I am back to square one! It's visible when eclipse is not run as root but invisible otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. I solve it by adding a new perspective and configure it.
I dont know i understand it well but I assume the reason is:

```
/home/userdir/.your.eclipse.config
```

and if u run eclipse as root, your config path is

```
/.your_eclipse_config
```

try to look after some eclipse folder in your / directory and then try to copy&paste it to your user dir or create new perspective by running as user

//UPD
I read it otherwise, so u have to copy &paste from user dir to root

Comment: Sorry, I don't find a config directory for eclipse as you mentioned in /home/userdir but a .eclipse directory. I copied that to /. Not working if that's what you wanted me to do.

BTW, I have installed eclipse in /opt by downloading it. I did not install the old eclipse given by Ubuntu typing apt-get install eclipse.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897223/java-perspective-is-not-visible-in-eclipse)
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033201/no-java-project-option-in-eclipse)
try to read this threads and tell what u achive. Look for your eclipse WORKSPACE and as i said before, try to create new ones, are they stay ?

Comment: Thank you. But, links did not solve the problem. I don't want to reinstall eclipse. I had problems with factory version installed using apt-get install and I downloaded zipped file by my own and installed the later version.